# Update custome View via Thread extanded class : Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bitmap

**What I have:**
I have CustomView class in which i am printing a `Bitmap image;` on `point position;`

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(carSpriteImage, carspritePosition.x , carspritePosition.y, null);
}//end of OnDraw
```

**I Want**
I want to update position via thread

```
public class AnimationHelperThread extends Thread{

CustomeView customeView;

public AnimationHelperThread(CustomeView customeView){
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.customeView=customeView;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    super.run();

    int x=0;
    int y=0;
    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
    {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(400);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Point p=new Point();
        p.set(x,y);
        customeView.setCarspritePosition(p);
        x+=1;
        y+=2;
        Log.i("Helper Thread", "Call "+i);
    }
}
```

This method is not working please suggest me any thing

Comment: Have you ever tried calling `customeView.invalidate();` after setting your point object?

Comment: Yeah i tried but it gave exception "call from wrong thread"

Comment: I cannot predict the reason of exception by looking at the code above. Only thing that I can say, you should be required to update view on `UI Thread` There's a function called `runOnUiThread(...)`. Try to use this function it may be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can only change layout from `UIThread`. Try something like this.-

Add a `Context` variable to your custom thread.-

```
Context context;

public AnimationHelperThread(Context context, CustomeView customeView) {
    // TODO Please, remove nasty autogenerated TODO comments
    this.context = context;
    this.customeView = customeView;
}
```

Then, assuming you're instantiating the thread from an `Activity`, you'll do.-

```
AnimationHelperThread thread = new AnimationHelperThread(this, customView);
```

And finally, call `runOnUiThread` through `context`.-

```
context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Point p=new Point();
        p.set(x,y);
        customeView.setCarspritePosition(p);
    }
});
```

Notice you'll need to define `x` and `y` as instance variables.

Comment: Mmh not necessarily, but there should be no issues if you do.

Comment: Error is runOnUiThread is undefined for type AnimationHelperThread

Comment: Right, my bad, you'll need to pass `context` to `AnimationHelperThread` instance. An instance of the calling activity will be fine.

Comment: can you give me example in code so i can understand better ... actually i am new in animation so i need a way to calculate position in other thread and UI thread just handle user input.

Comment: Sure, please, post relevant code where you create the thread, I'm guessing you do from an Activity, don't you?

Comment: I tried to post code but StackOverFlow ask some stupid requirment. can you share email_Id on which i can send you code